# birt viewer: layout different when export to pdf

Tags: pdf, layout, report, alignment, birt

I'm a newbye in Birt. I'm using Eclipse "all in one version" for development (Report Designer Release Build: 4.2.1). 
When I develop a report and run it into eclipse for test, everything seems to be ok.
The problem became if I deploy the report under the web-application "Birt Report Viewer" on Application Server Tomcat (6.0.32). If I launch it, all the label seems to be set with left alignment. If I export the report to PDF everything is ok.
So, the problem seems to be only on "Birt Report Viewer" when the report is render.
Any idea ?

Thanks
      GG

Comment: Everything works fine on IE but not on Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by setting the property Text Alignment to Center.
It seems that by default is setted by "Center:Inherited" and so here you are the steps to the right solution:

1. Set the property Text Alignment with another value (Ex: Justify)
2. Save the report
3. Set again the property Text Alignment with correct value "Center"
4. Save the report

Only following those steps the property will be set correctly.